# Assoc. Array, get Element with special id

Tags: php, arrays, symfony

I have the assoc array alldept.
I want now the 'name' element from the array with the id e.g. '1';

How do I access the id and output the 'name'?

The id is saved in `$result[$i]['abteilung']`

Thank you very much!

```
$manager = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getManager('olddb')
                ->getRepository('ChrisOldUserBundle:BpDepartment');
$dept = $manager->findBy([],['name' => 'ASC']);
$alldept = array();
foreach ($dept as $singledpt){
    $alldept[] = array("id" => $singledpt->getId(), 
                       "name" => $singledpt->getName()
                      );
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are building this array yourself it would seem sensible to build it in a way that is later usable.

So why not build the array like this

```
$manager = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getManager('olddb')
                ->getRepository('ChrisOldUserBundle:BpDepartment');
$dept = $manager->findBy([],['name' => 'ASC']);
$alldept = array();
foreach ($dept as $singledpt) {
    $alldept[ $singledpt->getId() ] = $singledpt->getName();
}
```

Now if you know you want the name of dept = 1 you just do

```
echo $alldept[1];
```

Comment: you were too quick ! :D

Answer (score 1):

What I would suggest is to keep  `id` as key and `name` as value:

```
$manager = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getManager('olddb')
                ->getRepository('ChrisOldUserBundle:BpDepartment');
$dept = $manager->findBy([],['name' => 'ASC']);
$alldept = array();
foreach ($dept as $singledpt){
    $alldept[$singledpt->getId()] = $singledpt->getName();
 }
```

> Note: I am assuming `getId` will be unique

Then to fetch `name`, you can simply type `$alldept[$id]`.

This might not be an answer, just an alternative. You can avoid a loop.

Comment: I will share a upvote with you, as you metioned the need for `getId` to be unique and I just assumed it was.

Comment: @RiggsFolly did the same, you deserve it for your quick response. OP got perfect help in 8 mins.